# all.js root is null

Tags: javascript, facebook

When loading my app all.js is throwing the following in IE8 at line 6:

Line: 6
Error: 'root' is null or not an object

As far as I know nothing changed on my page that should be causing this error, is anyone else seeing this crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing the fb-root div?
`<div id="fb-root"></div>`

The JS SDK attaches itself to this div

Comment: I actually had this in my code but at some point it (erroneously) made it's way into the <head> block. Made me notice that and now it works! Thanks!